# Less redundant way to make instances of a "circular" enum typeclass

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I have a snippet of code in which I have declared two datatypes. I've auto-derived both as members of the typeclass `enum`, however, I dislike that they are not "circular". By this, I mean that calling `succ Sun` should yield me `Mon`. `succ Dec` should result in `Jan`. So instead of writing my own enum I did this:

```
data WeekDay = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun
             deriving (Enum, Show, Eq, Bounded)

data Month = Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | July | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov 
             | Dec
           deriving (Enum, Show, Eq, Bounded)

class Circ a where
  next :: Enum a => a -> a

instance Circ WeekDay where
  next a = if a == maxBound then minBound else succ a

instance Circ Month where      -- this is nearly identical to the one above
  next a = if a == maxBound then minBound else succ a
```

My question is: Is there a neater, less redundant way of writing this? In other words, I have two nearly identical instances written, with the datatype name (WeekDay vs. Month) being the only variable that changed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class (Enum a, Bounded a, Eq a) => Circ a where
     next :: a -> a
     next a = if a == maxBound then minBound else succ a

instance Circ WeekDay
instance Circ Month
```

Comment: Yes this works but change your type constraint to (Enum a, Bounded a, Eq a)

Comment: @eazar001 Well, I personally prefer it this way. Why? The way you write it yo pretend somehow that there could be a type that is an instance of Circ without being also an instance of Eq, Bounded and Enum. But this is not possible, because `next` requires them. So, if only for documentation purposes, I prefer the former.

Comment: I see, I have seen arguments from both camps, one saying that class constraints are implied in function type signature, and that class constraints are unnecessary, and now from you .... following a "more readable" argument. I see your point though, I will leave that up to the reader then.

Comment: You are still free to do it like you want.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to build on Ingo's answer by pointing out that you don't actually need to define a type class at all.  You can just define the following function without invoking any additional type class:

```
next :: (Eq a, Bounded a, Enum a) => a -> a
next a = if a == maxBound then minBound else succ a
```

Now you don't have to declare `instance Circ` for all of your types.

Comment: You're absolutely right; however, the reason I chose to implement this functionality via typeclasses, is because I didn't want to provide the ability for any datatype with the constraints `(Eq a, Bounded a, Enum a)` to have access to `next`. Basically, I only wanted my two listed datatypes to be instances. Call it over-cautious, but that was just a precaution I excercised in my mind when approaching my problem.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you can do the following if you enable the `FlexibleInstances` and `UndecidableInstances` extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

instance (Eq a, Bounded a, Enum a) => Circ a where
  next e = if e == maxBound then minBound else succ e
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add `prev` too

```
class (Enum a, Bounded a, Eq a) => Circ a where
     next :: a -> a
     next a = if a == maxBound then minBound else succ a
     prev :: a -> a
     prev a = if a == minBound then maxBound else pred a
```

Comment: True, I just didn't have a reason to implement it, so I decided to keep the code as lean as possible, until the need arises. Thanks though.